# My Sign in Button won't navigate to the SignUpForm

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, stack-navigator

Inside my Account.js is my login form which displays my login form. However when the user presses the SignUp button the Sign Up screen is supposed to display, however nothing happens. The button works and I have no errors so why doesn't my SignUp screen appear after the button is pressed. Can someone show me what to do and explain why?

**LoginForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Button, CardSection, Input, Spinner } from './common';
import Account from './screens/Account';
import SignUpForm from './SignUpForm';
import router from '../config/router';

const AccountStack = StackNavigator({
  Account: {
    screen: Account,
    navigationOptions: {
    title: 'Account',
    headerBackTitle: null,
  },
},
  SignUpForm: {
    screen: SignUpForm,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Register'
    },
  },
});
class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Username or email"
          placeholderTextColor='white'
          returnKeyType='next'
          style={styles.input}
          keyboardType="email-address"
          onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
        />

        <TextInput
          secureTextEntry //turns text into *** good for passwords
          label="Password"
          placeholder="password"
          placeholderTextColor='white'
          secureTextEntry
          returnKeyType='go'
          style={styles.input}
          ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
        />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Need help logging in?{'\n'}
          or
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.divider} />
      <TouchableOpacity
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
        style={styles.buttonContainer}
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpForm')}
      >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign Up</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 20
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
   backgroundColor: '#FCD183',
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: 'white',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
    buttonContainer: {
      backgroundColor: '#FCBA12',
      paddingVertical: 15,
      marginBottom: 10,
      borderRadius: 10
  },
    divider: {
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
    buttonText: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: 'white'

    },
    textStyle: {
      color: 'white',
      textAlign: 'center',
      marginTop: 10,
      marginBottom: 10
    }
});

export default LoginForm;
```

**Account.js:**

```
        import React from 'react';
    import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
    import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    import { Card, Button, Spinner, CardSection } from '../common';
    import LoginForm from '../LoginForm';
    import router from '../../config/router';

    class Account extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarLabel: 'Account'
      }
      render() {
        return (<View style={styles.containerStyle}>
          <Card>
            <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../../Images/ShoeJackCityLogo.png')}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <LoginForm
                navigation={this.props.navigation}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpForm')}
              />
            </View>
          </Card>
        </View>);
      }
    }

    const styles = {
      containerStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F13C20',
        paddingBottom: 20
      },
      logoContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        paddingBottom: 0
      },
      logo: {
        paddingTop: 15,
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      },
      registerContainer: {
        padding: 20
      },
      input: {
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: '#FCD183',
        marginBottom: 10,
        color: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        borderRadius: 10
      },
      buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#FCBA12',
        paddingVertical: 15,
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderRadius: 10
      },
      divider: {
        borderBottomColor: 'black',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10
      },
      buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white'

      },
      textStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10
      }
    };

    export default Account;
```

**SignUpForm.js:**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Button, CardSection, Input, Spinner } from './common';


class SignUpForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Username or email"
          placeholderTextColor='white'
          returnKeyType='next'
          style={styles.input}
          keyboardType="email-address"
          onSubmitEditing={() => this.EmailInput.focus()}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor='white'
          returnKeyType='next'
          style={styles.input}
          keyboardType="email-address"
          onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
        />


        <TextInput
          secureTextEntry //turns text into *** good for passwords
          label="Password"
          placeholder="password"
          placeholderTextColor='white'
          secureTextEntry
          returnKeyType='go'
          style={styles.input}
          ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
        />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  registerContainer: {
    padding: 20
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
   backgroundColor: '#FCD183',
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: 'white',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
    buttonContainer: {
      backgroundColor: '#FCBA12',
      paddingVertical: 15,
      marginBottom: 10,
      borderRadius: 10
  },
    divider: {
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
    buttonText: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: 'white'

    },
    textStyle: {
      color: 'white',
      textAlign: 'center',
      marginTop: 10,
      marginBottom: 10
    }
});

export default SignUpForm;
```

**Router.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm';
import Tournaments from '../components/screens/Tournaments';
import Account from '../components/screens/Account';
import Artists from '../components/screens/Artists';
import Shop from '../components/screens/Shop';
import SignUpForm from '../components/SignUpForm';

export const AccountStack = StackNavigator({
  Account: {
    screen: Account,
    navigationOptions: {
    title: 'Account',
    headerBackTitle: null,
  },
  SignUpForm: {
    screen: SignUpForm,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Register'
    }
  },
  },
  Tournaments: {
    screen: Tournaments,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Tournaments',
      headerBackTitle: null,
      headerBackButton: null
    },
  },
  LoginForm: {
    screen: LoginForm,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Login',
      headerBackTitle: null,
      headerBackButton: null
    },
  },
  Artists: {
    screen: Artists,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Artists',
      headerBackTitle: null,
      headerBackButton: null
    },
  },
  Shop: {
    screen: Shop,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Shop',
      headerBackTitle: null,
      headerBackButton: null
    },
  },
});
export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Account: {
      screen: AccountStack,
      navigationOptions: {
          tabBarlabel: Account,
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon
          name="account-circle"
          size={35}
          color={tintColor}
          renderBackButton={() => (null)}
          />
        }
      },
  Tournaments: {
    screen: Tournaments,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: Tournaments,
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon
        name="tournament"
        size={35}
        color={tintColor}
        renderBackButton={() => (null)}
      />

    }
 },
 Shop: {
   screen: Shop,
   navigationOptions: {
     tabBarLabel: Shop,
       tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon
       name="shopping-bag"
       size={35}
       color={tintColor}
       renderBackButton={() => (null)}
       />

   }
 },
 Artists: {
   screen: Artists,
   navigationOptions: {
     tabBarLabel: Artists,
       tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon
       name="shopping-bag"
       size={35}
       color={tintColor}
       renderBackButton={() => (null)}
       />
   }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject navigation using [withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html). In this case try injecting it to LoginForm.